# Is it possible to use two filters on one layer in maputnik

Tags: filter, json, maputnik

I'm using Maputnik and thunderforest to create a map layout and I want to show the English labels of a city only if they do not match with the original name of the city AND if there is an original name of the city. I think I would be needing to filter in this layer, but I can't figure out how. I'm currently doing this, but it doesn't work.

```
{
  "id": "tf-place-town-english",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "thunderforest",
  "source-layer": "place-label",
  "filter": {
     ["has", ["get", "name"]],
     ["!=", ["get", "name"], ["get", "name_en"]]
   }
 }
```

I guess that i shouldn't be using two arrays to filter, but what I can't figure out what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this. In the filter you have to specify "all" before you type the different filters you want to apply, like this:

```
{
  "id": "tf-place-town-english",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "thunderforest",
  "source-layer": "place-label",
  "filter": [
      "all", 
      ["!=", ["get", "name"], ["get", "name_en"]],
      ["has", ["get", "name"]]
   ]
}
```